# Difference between box topology and uniform topology

Tags: general-topology

I need a specific logic and examples of difference between box and product topology though I know that box is finer but it is too hard to visualise the difference.

Comment: Perhaps an example will clarify the difference.  Let S be the set of all functions from R into R.  The set all functions from R into (0,1) is open by both topologies for S.  The set all functions f, from R with for all x /= 0, f (x) in (0,1) and f (0) in R is open only the box topology.

Answer (score 1):

In [this note](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/17.pdf) I explain the different connected components of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ in the three topologies as discussed in Munkres (product, uniform metric and box topology). The arguments there might give you a feel for the difference.